# Kafka 0.10.0 MetricsReporter implementation doing nothing past initialization

Tags: apache-kafka

I have a very simple Metrics Reporter that implements the Kafka 0.10.0 MetricsReporter interface, that takes in the metrics as a parameter and logs them. When a producer starts to send messages, I can see that it is correctly configured to use the Metrics Reporter I created because it starts to log, but it only seems to log in the beginning around initialization and almost every value seems to be 0.0 or negative infinity (besides available buffer, metadata-age, and the metric count starts at 1.0 after initialization). The reporter also stops receiving metrics a very short time after startup. When looking at the JMX Metrics Reporting on a server running my Kafka setup, all of the values exist, which makes it clear that the 0.0s are not expected output.

After exploring this problem for a while, it looks like this has nothing to do with the implementation of the Metrics Reporter and more to do with some configuration issue or understanding around how Metrics Reporting works.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same thing with my consumer. Did you figure this out?